# SQL Server 2008 Unpivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Background:
--Data used to create table within the Recipes database.

```
USE [Recipes]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Recipe7](
    [RecipeID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [item1] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [item2] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [item3] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [item4] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [item5] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [item6] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [item7] [varchar](500) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

--Results of first 5 rows

```
Select Top(5)  RecipeID, Item1,Item2,Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6, Item7
from Recipe7

Pivot Table Results (Multiple Spaces = Column Break)
121302  6 red apples    1 1/2 cup sugar 1/2 cup light corn syrup    1/2 cup water Few grains salt   1/2 teaspoon red food color 1/2 teaspoon vanilla    
121304  2 (20 oz.) cans sliced Comstock  apples drained (NOT pie filling)   1/4 cup butter or margarine melted  1 cup sugar 1/2 cup orange juice    1/4 cup flour   2 tablespoon grated orange rind 
121305  8-10 slices French bread cubed  1 large can pineapple chunks drained    2 eggs beaten   2 cup white sugar   1 cup melted butter     
121306  1 (#2 1/2) can (29 oz.) peach halves    1 tablespoon white vinegar  1 tablespoon mixed pickling spices  1 teaspoon whole cloves 1 stick cinnamon        
121307  4 cup hot water 46 oz. can pineapple juice  1 (6 oz.) can frozen lemonade   2 cup sugar 46 oz. can orange juice 1/2 cup crushed maraschino cherries 1/2 cup crushed pineapple   1 bottle ginger ale
```

--Unpivot query

```
Select RecipeID, Item, Ingredients
from 
    (Select RecipeID, item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7
    from Recipe7) r
Unpivot
    (Ingredients for Recipe In
        (item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7)
) AS unpvt;
```

--Error Message

```
Error Text
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Item'.
```

I am trying to convert a column in an old recipe database called Ingredients into a new table.  The old data was delimited and in Excel I was able to covert it into the format above which consist of one ingredient per column in a new table called Recipe7.

I have been out of the field for 4 years as I am retired.  When I was a DBA and Database Architect, I never really used Pivot and Unpivot so this is new to me.  I am following an example from a Microsoft website but can work with what ever you give me.

Thanks for your help and take it easy on an OLD man :)

Comment: The error is quite clear - the `Item` column doesn't exist. Change the first line of your select query

Answer (score 3):

```
Select RecipeID, Item, Ingredients
from 
    (Select RecipeID, item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7
    from Recipe7) r
Unpivot
    (Ingredients for Item In
        (item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7)
) AS unpvt;
```